# ¿Cómo ingresar a una lista doble enlazada más de un archivo de dato?

Tags: java, netbeans, lista, archivo, estructuras-de-datos

Buenas noches a todos.
Estoy codificando una aplicación que permite leer un archivo .csv de horarios, estudiantes, cursos y asignaciones de una institución educativa y éstos archivos los debo colocar en una lista doblemente enlazada. Mi aplicación puede leer éstos cuatro archivos pero la forma en que intento ponerlos a la lista no funciona y tengo excepciones que no estoy seguro por que razón salen.

```
 public void insertarHorario(Horario horario) {

    Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(horario);
    Nodo aux;
    aux = cabeza;

    if (cabeza == null) {
        cabeza = nuevo;
    } else {

        aux = cabeza;

        while (aux.siguiente != null) {
            aux = aux.siguiente;
        }

        aux.siguiente = nuevo;
        nuevo.anterior = aux;

    }

}

public void insertarAsignacion(Asignacion asignacion) {

    Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(asignacion);
    Nodo aux;
    aux = cabeza;

    if (cabeza == null) {
        cabeza = nuevo;
    } else {

        aux = cabeza;

        while (aux.siguiente != null) {
            aux = aux.siguiente;
        }

        aux.siguiente = nuevo;
        nuevo.anterior = aux;

    }

}

 public void insertarFinal(Asignacion asignacion) {
    Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(asignacion);
    Nodo aux = cabeza;

    if (esVacia()) {

        insertarCabeza(asignacion);

    } else {

        while (aux.siguiente != null) {

            aux = aux.siguiente;

            insertarCabeza(hou);

        }
        aux.siguiente = nuevo;
        nuevo.anterior = aux;

    }
    }

    public void insertarCabeza(Asignacion asig) {
    Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(asig);
    if (esVacia()) {
        cabeza = nuevo;
    }
}
```

Éstos métodos ingresan al inicio de la lista.

He pensado que para colocar cada archivo necesitaba un método insertar para cada archivo pero lo único que logro con esto es que al ingresar la palabra "Horario" o "Asignacion" en consola para que lea el archivo y lo ingrese a la lista me funcione solamente una vez, es decir, si agrego el archivo horario.csv me muestra en consola la información que contiene bien, pero cuando quiero asignación no me muestra la información que se supone.

```
 public void mostrarE(String ruta) {
    System.out.println("El archivo es: " + ruta);

    Nodo aux;
    aux = cabeza;


    while (aux != null ) {
        if (ruta.equals("Horario")) {
            System.out.println("******" + aux.datosHorario.getID_HORARIO() + "*******");
            System.out.println("******" + aux.datosHorario.getCURSO() + "*******");
            System.out.println("******" + aux.datosHorario.getSECCION() + "*******");
            System.out.println("******" + aux.datosHorario.getEDIFICIO() + "*******");
            System.out.println("******" + aux.datosHorario.getSALON() + "*******");
        }                       
        else if (ruta.equals("Asignacion")) {

            System.out.println("******" + aux.datosAsignacion.getCARNET() + "*******");
            System.out.println("******" + aux.datosAsignacion.getID_HORARIO() + "*******");
            System.out.println("******" + aux.datosAsignacion.getNOTA_FINAL() + "*******");

        }
        aux = aux.siguiente;
    }

}
```

Luego he intentado ingresar "horario" al inicio de la lista y "asignacion" al final, y ya me imprime los datos de "asignacion.csv" aunque sea el primero que escriba en consola, pero cuando quiero visualizar los datos de "horario.csv" me manda un

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at practica.Lista.mostrarE(Lista.java:134)
at practica.importarCSV.mostrarLista(importarCSV.java:134)
```

Ésta es mi clase donde importo mis archivos, cada uno respectivamente, usando el método de ingresar al inicio y final de la lista.

```
 public class importarCSV {

Lista datosE = new Lista();
File fila, filaE, filaA, filaC;

String rutaA;
int identificador = 0;

public void leerCsv(String ruta) {
    rutaA = ruta;

    switch (rutaA) {
        case "Asignacion":
            String asignacion = "src/ArchivosEntrada/asignacion.csv";
            filaA = new File(asignacion);
            identificador = 1;
            break;
        case "Curso":
            String cursos = "src/ArchivosEntrada/cursos.csv";
            filaC = new File(cursos);
            identificador = 2;
            break;
        case "Estudiante":
            String estudiantes = "src/ArchivosEntrada/estudiantes.csv";
            filaE = new File(estudiantes);
            identificador = 3;
            break;
        case "Horario":
            String horario = "src/ArchivosEntrada/horario.csv";
            fila = new File(horario);
            identificador = 4;

            break;
        default:

    }

    cargar(identificador, rutaA);

}

public void cargar(int i, String rut) {

    switch (i) {
        case 1:
            cargarAsignacion(rut);
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            cargarEstudiante(rut);
            break;
        case 4:
            cargarHorario(rut);
            break;
        default:
    }
}

public void cargarHorario(String ruta) {
    try {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(fila);
        while (entrada.hasNext()) {

            String datos = entrada.next();
            String[] valores = datos.split(",");

            System.out.println(valores[0] + "," + valores[1] + "," + valores[4]);

            datosE.insertarHorario(new Horario(valores[0], valores[1], valores[2], valores[3], valores[4]));

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Archivo no encontrado.");
    }
}


public void cargarAsignacion(String ruta) {
    try {

        Scanner entradaA = new Scanner(filaA);
        while (entradaA.hasNext()) {

            String datosA = entradaA.next();
            String[] valoresA = datosA.split(",");

            datosE.insertarFinal(new Asignacion(valoresA[0], valoresA[1], valoresA[2]));

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Archivo no encontrado.");
    }
}

public void mostrarLista() {
    this.datosE.mostrarE(rutaA);
}
```

}

Todo esto no me esta funcionando bien y no comprendo muy bien a que se deberá tales errores. 
Si alguien puede ayudarme con éste código o darme alguna idea de otra forma en que podría hacerlo estaría muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1):

El primer problema que veo es en el método de mostrarE. Pasas por todos los nodos de tu lista y si lo solicitado es "asignación", le pedirás al nodo los datos de la asignación sin revisar primero que el nodo actual es de tipo asignación.

Si primero cargas horarios, luego cargas asignación, y pides datos de la asignación, primero revisará los horarios y pedira `aux.datosAsignacion.getCARNET()`de horarios, el cuál no los tiene y te arroja  el NullPointerException.

La solución es que puedas revisar de qué tipo es el objeto. Si el tipo corresponde con lo que están solicitando, entonces procedes a leer los datos, si no lo es, avanzas al siguiente nodo a revisar si es del tipo solicitado, y así sucesivamente hasta encontrar ( o no ) el tipo de dato buscado.